# CUDA nvlink warning : SM Arch ('sm_35') not found

Tags: c++, cuda

yesterday installed cuda-6.5 to my ubunutu14.04. I followed the steps stated in [cuda's getting started guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html#introduction). Checked for System requirements and mine was OK. Did pre-installations, uninstalled previously installed cuda, and installed package manager installation. All these steps were successfully performed. I skipped steps runfile installation and croos-build environment fro arm. In [post-installation actions][2] step, added

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-6.5/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

these lines to .profile file. I upgraded my driver to the latest available driver by running the command `sudo apt-get install cuda-drivers`. Also verified that I installed correct driver. Rebooted my computer and vaulla cuda-6.5 is build successfully. But when I compile my simpleCuda.cu file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include<iostream>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/logical.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <cublas_v2.h>



using namespace std;

int main(){
        float* dev,host;

        cudaError_t stat = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev,10*sizeof(float));
        cout << "stat " << stat << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

with `nvcc -arch=sm_35 -rdc=true -lcublas -lcublas_device -lcudadevrt -o my simpleCuda.cu` compile parameters set I got a warning message

```
nvlink warning : SM Arch ('sm_35') not found in '/usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublas_device.a:maxwell_sgemm.asm.o'
nvlink warning : SM Arch ('sm_35') not found in '/usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublas_device.a:maxwell_sm50_sgemm.o'
```

`

. In [this link](http://www.tagwith.com/question_368892_cublas-matrix-inversion-from-device/) I see that it can be ignored. But I don't want to ignore this message. I compiled this simpleCuda.cu with the same compilation parameters set on different computer with cuda-5.5 compilation tool. It does not give me any warning message about architecture linking (-arch=sm_35). I want to get rid of this warning message. These compile parameters are not necessary for this particular code I posted, but further I will need them. I appreciate all your help.

Comment: Why are you using separate compilation and linking cublas and the device runtime library for a single file with no device code and no cublas library calls?

Comment: Switch to CUDA 7 (production release) when it becomes available.  The issue should be fixed, I believe.  It is not fixed yet in CUDA 7 RC.  In the meantime, if you simply want to make the nvlink warning messages go away, you can add `-Xnvlink -w` to your compile command.  If that is not acceptable then the only suggestion I can offer is wait until CUDA 7 production release.  Until then, warnings of this type are benign.

Comment: Hello Robert, thank you for your advice. I will wait for CUDA 7 then. Hi talonmies, you right currently I am not doing anything with cublas and device runtime library, but in the near future I am planning to use them. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was apparently a toolchain limitation which was rectified in the CUDA 7 production release.

[This answer was assembled from comments to get the question off the unanswered queue for the CUDA tag]